# PyWPS output created but not accesible by the Javascript client

Tags: javascript, wps, pywps

- The good thing: I've a working PyWPS process.
- The bad thing: I cannot access the output using the PyWPS Javascript client.

**What I did.**

I created an PyWPS python script with one `LiteralInput` (`type=FloatType`) and one `ComplexOutput` (`formats='mimeType':'xml/application'`) from the browser accessible by:

> `localhost/cgi-bin/pywps.cgi?REQUEST=Execute&IDENTIFIER=pyhants&SERVICE=WPS&VERSION=1.0.0&DATAINPUTS=input_ts=3`

And gives the following output:

[image]

This seems to be OK.

I've created a [PyWPS Javascript Client](http://pywps.wald.intevation.org/documentation/pywps-3.2/clients/javascript.html) and tried two options, one by hand and one automatic. The one manually only gives me `null` as output, but the automatic gives output. It provide a URL as a reference as seen below:

[image]

That's fine, and if I look in this folder this file is created, is accessible and contains output. But if I try to access this URL from within my browser it tells me that the requested URL was not found on the server. As can be seen in the following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2/448955#448955) on askubuntu.com:

The apache2 version that was published when the Ubuntu 14.04 release was made is 2.4.7 and starting with this version it seems that, for security reasons, the new root directory for the server is:

```
/var/www/html
```

So, from now, here you must to place the files for your (local) website. And like this you should not have this problem again with the future updates.

Anyway, if you want to change this directory with another one, you have to modify (as root) the following line from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file (`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

After these, to take effect the new changes , you must to restart apache server using the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```